# Let $X$ and $Y$ random variables on the same probability space, such that $E[Y^2|X] = X^2$ a. e. and $E[Y|X] = X$ a. e. Show that $Y = X$ a. e.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

If I had that $Y$ and $Y^2$ be integrable, then $Y^2=E[Y^2|X]=YE[Y|X]=XY$ a. e. (Th. $34.3$ of Billingley's "Probability and measure"), then $X(\omega)Y(\omega)=X^2(\omega)$ a. e. and then either $X(\omega)=Y(\omega)$ a. e., or $X(\omega) \equiv 0$ a.e. In the second case, by definition of conditional expectation, $0 \equiv X^2=E[Y^2|X]$ is a $\sigma(X)$-measurable random variable such that its integral in $\Omega$ equals the integral of $Y^2$ in $\Omega$, i.e. $Y^2$ integrated in a set of probability $1$ equals $0$, and since $Y^2$ is positive, then it has to be 0 a. e., giving again $X \equiv 0 \equiv Y^2 \equiv Y$ a. e.

I think this argument is ok, but I don't have the integrability of $Y$ and $Y^2$ in the hypothesis, and I don't know if there is an easy way to overcome that.

Comment: Hint: try to show $\mathbb{E}(X-Y)^2 \equiv 0$.

Comment: @Federico : I cannot follow your argument $Y^2=E[Y^2|X]$ (why?) and $E[Y^2|X]=YE[Y|X]$ (why?) whereas the proof using openspace's hint $E[(X-Y)^2]$ seems a straightforward application of iterated expectations. All of this assuming second moments are finite.  It seems that solidifying your proof in that simpler case is more important than generalizing to a harder case.

Comment: Anyway I would think existence of $E[Y^2|X]$ would presuppose that $Y^2$ has finite expectation.

Comment: @Michael The almost sure finiteness of $\ E(Y^2|X)\ $ doesn't imply that of $\ E(Y^2)\ $.  Take $\ Y=X\ $ where $\ X\ $ follows a [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution), for instance.  However, it's possible to show that $\ E\big((Y-X)^2\big)=0\ $ without assuming that the (necessarily common) distribution of $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $ has finite mean or variance.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera The standard L1 definition of $E[W|X]$ requires $E[|W|]<\infty$. It needs to satisfy $E[E[W|X|1_{X\in A}]=E[W1_{X\in A}]$ for all $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and in particular with $A = \mathbb{R}$ we need $E[E[W|X]]=E[W]$ so $E[W]$ needs to exist. Your example with $W=X$ Cauchy does not work.  So to even talk about $E[Y^2|X]$ we would first need $E[|Y^2|]<\infty$, that is $E[Y^2]<\infty$. Unless you are using some nonstandard conditional expectation definition.

Comment: @Michael My apologies. I'm aware that conditional expectation has been defined in lots of different ways for different levels of generality. The one I have always used is the one [given on p.159](https://archive.org/details/introductiontopr02fell_0/page/159/mode/1up) of my ancient edition of Feller's *An Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications*, Vol II. However, my knowledge of modern literature on the subject is rather sketchy, and I wasn't aware that the less general definition you refer to had since acquired the status of a "standard".

Comment: Nevertheless, on consulting some more modern advanced texts on the subject, I agree this does appear to be the case. Feller, however, first defines the conditional *distribution* of a random variable $\ Y\ $ given another, and then defines its conditional expectation in terms of that conditional distribution. The assertions I made in my earlier comment were intended to be about the concept of conditional expectation as defined by Feller, and as such, I believe they're correct. In particular, I don't believe his definition requires  $\ E(|Y|)\ $ to be finite.

Comment: How do you or Feller define the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$? @lonzaleggiera

Comment: Feller defines a conditional distribution of $\ Y\ $ given $\ X\ $  to be any function $\ q:\mathbb{R}\times\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow[0,1]\ $ satisfying the following two conditions:$$
\text{(i)}\hspace{2em}P(X\in A,Y\in B)=\int_Aq(x,B)\mu(dx)\ $$
for all $\ A,B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\ $, where $\ \mu\ $ is the marginal distribution of $\ X\ $, and
$$\text{(ii) For each }\ x\in\mathbb{R},\  q(x,\cdot)\ \text{ is a probability distribution.}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
$$
E\big((Y-X)^2)=E\big(E\big((Y-X)^2\big|\,X\big))\ .
$$
What is $\ E\big((Y-X)^2\big|\,X\big)\ $?